# Chamar metodo na action de um form que invoca qual pagina deve ser redirecionada

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ao inserir um valor no input text, devo consultar o banco para verificar se o mesmo existe. Caso positivo, devo redirecionar para formDetails.php. Caso negativo, devo redirecionar para formRegister.php.

Venho trabalhando a algumas hora a respeito e não consigo encontrar solução.
HTML e Javascript se encontram em um mesmo arquivo.

```
<!--FILTRO FLUTUANTE -->
    <div id="mws-themer">
        <div id="mws-themer-hide"></div>
        <div id="mws-themer-content">
            <div class="mws-themer-section">
                <form action="" name="myForm" id="myForm" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="edtMFIR" id="edtMFIR" value="" class="mws-textinput error">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mws-themer-separator"></div>
            <div class="mws-themer-section">
                <button type="button" onclick="submit()" class="mws-button red small" id="mws-themer-sendfilterPCD">Filtrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <script>

        function submit() {

            var fornDetails = "fornDetails.php";
            var fornRegister = "fornRegister.php";

            var result = "<?php paginaDestino($_POST["edtMFIR"]); ?>";
            alert(result);

            if (result) {
                myForm.action = fornRegister;

            } else {
                myForm.action = fornDetails;
            }
            myForm.submit();

        }
    </script>
```

Função onde faço a verificação no banco:

```
function paginaDestino($edtMFIR){

$conexao = new bancodedados();
if(!empty($edtMFIR)){
    $conexao->setSQL("SELECT * FROM tab_aro_pcd_riscos WHERE aro_riscos_mfir=".$edtMFIR." LIMIT 1");
$res_a = $conexao->Consultar();
    $RES_MFIR = mysql_fetch_array($res_a);

    if(empty($RES_MFIR)){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionei os vários erros que encontrei, provável que funcione dessa forma.

```
<?php 

function paginaDestino($edtMFIR){

$conexao = new bancodedados();
if(!empty($edtMFIR)){
    $conexao->setSQL("SELECT * FROM tab_aro_pcd_riscos WHERE aro_riscos_mfir=".$edtMFIR." LIMIT 1");
$res_a = $conexao->Consultar();
    $RES_MFIR = mysql_fetch_array($res_a);

    if(empty($RES_MFIR)){
        header('Location: fornRegister.php');//não seria form?
    }else{
        header('Location: fornDetails.php');
    }
}

}

if(isset($_POST['edtMFIR'])){paginaDestino($_POST['edtMFIR'])}

?>

<!--FILTRO FLUTUANTE -->
    <div id="mws-themer">
        <div id="mws-themer-hide"></div>
        <div id="mws-themer-content">
            <div class="mws-themer-section">
                <form action="" name="myForm" id="myForm" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="edtMFIR" id="edtMFIR" value="" class="mws-textinput error">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mws-themer-separator"></div>
            <div class="mws-themer-section">
                <button type="button" onclick="submit()" class="mws-button red small" id="mws-themer-sendfilterPCD">Filtrar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <script>

        function submit() {

            var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

            myForm.submit();

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Cara, você salvou a minha vida. Poderia me explicar o que realmente tava dando pau ?

Comment: Kk ai sim, você estava entrando em um looping, verificava a variável php no javascript sem ela estar setada, no exemplo acima deixei o php fazer todo o trabalho.

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz isso recentemente usando JQuery e Ajax, a função que voce procura é .keyup meu exemplo :

```
// Essa função verifica se o email ja existe e desabilita o botão 
function verif_email(email,nome) {
    var html = '<br>Você é o : \"' + nome + '\" ? <a href="#">Sim</a> / <a href="#">Não</a>';
    //essa condição é para caso a pagina ja carregue com um email no campo
    $('#email').ready(function() {
        if ($('#email').val() == email){
            $('#btn1').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#btn1').html("Email ja cadastrado");
            $('#texto').html(html);
        }else{
            $('#texto').hide();
        }
    });

    //essa condição é para ele checar cada vez que digitar
    $('#email').keyup(function() {
        if ($('#email').val() == email){
            $('#btn1').prop('disabled', true);
            $('#btn1').html("Email ja cadastrado");
            $('#texto').show();
            $('#texto').html(html);
        }else{
            $('#btn1').show();
            $('#btn1').html("Salvar");
            $('#btn1').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#alert').hide();
            $('#texto').hide();
        }
    });
}
function load_json() {
$.ajax({
    url : "json.json",
    success : function(result) {
        verif_email(result["email"],result["nome"]);
        setTimeout(function(){load_json();}, 100);
    }
});
```

}

espero ter ajudado.